# To what extent has the legality of property taxes been tested in American courts?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, real-property, legal-citation

In the United States, many State governments tax land property owners based on the value of the property. These taxes are assessed every year and must be paid or the state will seize your property and auction it to the highest bidder.

I'm wondering to what extent the legality of this practice (constitutional or otherwise) has been tested in American courts. America's founding was in part related to upset about some of the obscure taxing schemes of pre-industrial England. So called "double taxation" and even income tax are/were objectionable in the past. The annual taxing of property based on value seems suspect to me, so I presume some courts have tested it. I want to know what those cases are and the reasoning that concluded annual property taxing is legal.

Comment: I don't have cases to cite, but typically the argument goes like this: "Do you drive on a road to get to your house? When it snows, does it get plowed? When your house is burglarized, do the police show up? When your house is on fire, does the fire department show up? Do your children attend school? Does your township enforce laws to keep your home value up?" Yes? Then you need to pay for that.

Comment: And it isn't just state taxes on your home, there are usually county taxes, school district taxes, village/township/city taxes and others that are all assessed based on property value. If they didn't tax based on value, how would you do it? Should the guy with a $5m house down the road be paying as much as the couple with 3 kids and blue-collar jobs?

Comment: @Ron The argument for taxes is a strong one, but you haven't given an argument for the legality of property taxes. Both sales and income taxes are common and fundamentally different than property taxes.

Comment: I'm talking about those services being paid for by *property taxes*, not sales taxes. State taxes go into a general state fund, but local county/township taxes stay local to pay for local services like surface street repair, police and fire services, and school. The state does not pay for those things unless the city obtains a grant or loan from the state.

Comment: @RonBeyer I understand the appropriations. What you've said in comment however is not legal justification for property taxes. It's, at best, a philosophical agreement for the existence of taxes in general.

Comment: Do you have in mind a specific legal objection that would be raised, e.g. which part of the Constitution would be violated?  The issues with federal income taxes in the early 1900s would have nothing to do with state property taxes, and I can try to explain why in more detail if you like.  I don't know what "double taxation" refers to in your question; can you elaborate what you mean, how and when it was "objectionable", and why you think similar issues could apply to state property tax?

Comment: *'America's founding was in part related to upset about some of the obscure taxing schemes of pre-industrial England'* The issue was not simply taxation, it was specifically the imposition of taxation without representation in the government. The colonists had no representation in the English parliament, they therefore regarded the imposition of taxes without a voice in the government as a breach of 'English liberties' going back to the Magna Carta.

Comment: @NateEldredge The 5th amendment is the first that comes to mind. I know it's been used unsuccessfully against income taxes. In mentioning other taxes, I only mean to point out that Americans generally object to all taxes, therefore, legal objections are expected.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Among the more radical ones, like Sam Adams, it was more an objection against the taxes themselves, not just the lack of representation.

Comment: @fredsbend *'it was more an objection against the taxes themselves, not just the lack of representation'* Needs citation. In fact Sam worked for a number of years as a tax collector. One of his most famous quotes on taxess is [If Taxes are laid upon us in any shape **without our having a legal Representation where they are laid**, are we not reduced from the Character of free Subjects to the miserable State of tributary Slaves?](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Samuel_Adams)

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant *"No taxes can be devised which are not more or less inconvenient and unpleasant."* ;) - GW, who levied the Whiskey tax and rode personally to halt the ensuing rebellion. There were other tax related "rebellions" shortly after founding. As to Adams, he was then and still is a contentious figure, and since I'm not looking for a debate on that at the moment, I feel that's quite off-topic. My point is that anti-tax sentiment for a variety of reasons, not just for under-representation, and including as petty as "inconvenient and unpleasant", is perfectly American.

Comment: As such, I have expected property taxes to be challenged in various courts, but I am having trouble finding anything of great importance. Further, being only casually interested in legal things, determining importance of such things is itself difficult for me.

Comment: Pennsylvania abandoned an asset tax in the late 1990s after a challenge by billionaire Walter Annenberg, but in that case PA privileged PA assets, violating the Constitution's commerce clause.  https://caselaw.findlaw.com/pa-supreme-court/1043831.html

Comment: @user662852 That is interesting. Thank you. In general though, couldn't a "privileged" argument be made since property taxes are assessed based on market value (essentially arbitrary), rather than size, location, occupants, etc.? Cheaper property is arbitrarily privileged.

Comment: if your position is market value is arbitrary, i will point you to read up on 19th century economist Henry George.  That some states split property tax assessment on the value of land and improvements is due to his work.  https://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/bios/George.html

Comment: @Ron Beyer And the counter-argument is did the state squash any competition and granted monopolies to most favored institutions.

Comment: Mr. Washington was the reason for the 7-year-war (aka: French and Indian War) by [having a french delegation accidentally gunned down and then not stopping them from being scalped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Jumonville_Glen), and this made him unable to ever rise in rank - which was a big reason he ended on the side of the colonists.